# Julia Gtk: access active text from ComboBoxText

Tags: gtk, julia

The standard way to access active text from a combo box (PyGtk) is to do the following:

```
item_text = combo.get_active_text()
print item_text
```

Alternatively:

```
index = combo.get_active()
model = combo.get_model()
item = model[index]
print item[0] ## , item[1], ...
```

I am trying to access the current text in a "changed" callback on a ComboBoxText in Julia:

```
id_combobox = signal_connect(my_combobox, "changed") do widget

    # this works
    index = getproperty(widget,:active,Int32)
    println("index: ", index)

    # this does not
    model = getproperty(widget,:model,Vector{String})
    println("item: ", model[index])

    # this does not
    text = getproperty(widget,:active_text,String)
    println("item: ", text)

end
```

What is the proper way to get the active text from a ComboBoxText in Julia Gtk?

Is there a way to list the types alongside the properties for a widget? It took me a while to figure out that I had to use Int32 instead of Integer for :active.

Thank you

Comment: Use the `G_` accessor method (https://github.com/JuliaLang/Gtk.jl#objects-have-get-and-set-accessor-methods) as follows: `Gtk.G_.active_text(cb)`. This value can be converted to a string with `bytestring`.

Comment: It works! `text = bytestring(convert(Ptr{Uint8}, Gtk.G_.active_text(widget)))`